# Concat string in start of value

Tags: mysql, sql

Example:

```
345566677
345566677
345566677
345566677
```

I forgot to add +92 at the start of mobile number so i want to concat "+92"

here i m trying like this

```
UPDATE student SET cell1 = CONCAT(cell1, '+92') WHERE cell1 LIKE '%3%';
```

after running this query +92 add at the end of string i want to be at start 
somebody help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
UPDATE student
SET cell1 = CONCAT('+92', cell1)   
WHERE cell1 NOT LIKE '+92%';
```

I've assumed that you are storing phone number as `VARCHAR` and not numeric type.

Answer (score 1):

You Have to  Use `CONCAT()` function like this,

```
UPDATE student SET cell1 = CONCAT('+92',cell1) WHERE cell1 LIKE '%3%';
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to attach '+92' in the begining

```
UPDATE student SET cell1 = CONCAT('+92'cell1) WHERE cell1 LIKE '%3%';
```